# Redirection issue in Angular post request - 302 moved temporarily

Tags: java, angularjs, http, servlets

I'm trying to send a **POST** request using angular **$http** service, i keep getting the **302 moved temporarily** and i don't know how to proceed

```
        $scope.sendPareqFormToAcs = function(data) {
                    $http(
                            {
                                method : 'POST',
                                url : data.targetAcsLocation,
                                data : "PaReq=" + data.paReq + "&MD="
                                        + data.md + "&TermUrl="
                                        + data.termUrl,
                                headers : {
                                    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                                    'Accept-Language' : 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
                                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                }
                            }).success(function(data) {
                                alert("OK");
                    })
                };
```

The target that i'm trying to invoke using this post request is instance of **HttpServlet**, normally if things go 100 over 100, a redirection to another **xhtml** page should happen but i keep getting this response.

[image]

This is the detailed description of the Response.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope someone can help me out solving this issue, normally things should work, but it keeps falling at the redirection step at the Servlet Layer.

the redirection works fine with tests from other clients.

Answer (score 0):

This HTTP response code tell you that the requested resource has been moved to a new location and you should make a new request to the url provided in the location field.

In your case it's `http://.../validationAchat.xhhtml`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302